# C# - Dynamic code, reference issues and placement

Tags: c#

In my code, I'm reading a text file, compiling it and trying to run it,
I have an issue with references (I think) This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.Reflection;


namespace IFCViewer
{

static class Program
{
    static public void Main()
    {

        String code_file = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\tmp\my_code.txt");

        /* Element DB */
        List<DB.IFCArray> Element_list = new List<DB.IFCArray>();

        /* Relationships DB */
        List<DB.RelObj> Rel_list = new List<DB.RelObj>();

        bool Flag = false;

        CompileAndRun(code_file);


    }

    static void CompileAndRun(string code)
    {
        CompilerParameters CompilerParams = new CompilerParameters();
        string outputDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        CompilerParams.GenerateInMemory = true;
        CompilerParams.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
        CompilerParams.GenerateExecutable = false;
        CompilerParams.CompilerOptions = "/optimize";

        string[] references = { "System.dll","System.Windows.Forms.dll"};
        CompilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(references);

        CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        CompilerResults compile = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerParams, code);

        if (compile.Errors.HasErrors)
        {
            string text = "Compile error: ";
            foreach (CompilerError ce in compile.Errors)
            {
                text += "rn " + ce.ToString();
            }
            throw new Exception(text);
        }

        Module module = compile.CompiledAssembly.GetModules()[0];
        Type mt = null;
        MethodInfo methInfo = null;

        if (module != null)
        {
            mt = module.GetType("IFCViewer.Program");
        }

        if (mt != null)
        {
            methInfo = mt.GetMethod("Run_My_Code");
        }

        if (methInfo != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(methInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] {}));
        }
    }
```

The text file contains the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.Reflection;

namespace IFCViewer
{
public static class DynaCode
{
        static public void Run_My_Code(List<DB.IFCArray> Element_list,List<DB.RelObj> Rel_list,bool Flag)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Dynamic Code Running!!");
            }

     } 
}
```

The DB class is defined on a different file with the same namespace (IFCViewer).

```
namespace IFCViewer
{
public static class DB
{

 +       public class IFCArray
 +       public class RelObj 
}
```

I get a reference error: error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'DB' does not exist in the namespace 'IFCViewer' (are you missing an assembly reference?) when I try to compile and run the code from the file,
the compile and run method does work, I've tested it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well how do you expect the other code to pick up the `DB` class? If that's in another assembly, you need to include that in your references...

Comment: I thought having the same namespace should resolve the issue? How do I include that file to my reference?

Comment: Namespaces are irrelevant to visibility. Which assembly contains the `DB` class? That has to be included as a reference when you compile, basically.

Comment: The file that contains DB definition called "Semantic_Engine", how do I know which assembly contain it?

Comment: I really don't know what you mean - but it sounds like you need to take a step back and look at what the various assemblies are. Stack Overflow isn't an interactive debugging tool - you should clarify in your own mind and in your question what the various components of your system are, and how you expect this all to build.

Comment: I used the Get Assembly on DB to see which assembly contain it and included it in the reference when I complied. Working now, thanks again.